# JavaFX и многопоточность

Tags: java, многопоточность, javafx

Задача - при нажатии на определенную кнопку программы (JavaFX GUI) запустить гифку ожидания, которая будет крутиться, пока вполняется основной код. Для этого есть отдельный метод - showGif(), и его вызов через Platform.runLater отдельным потоком (запускается при нажатии на кнопку).

Проблема в том, что гифка по-прежнему запускается только после того, как весь код программы уже выполнен - т.е. не отдельным потоком в начале работы программы, как я хотел.

В похожих вопросах у людей все работает через Platform.runLater - что я делаю не так?

Действие кнопки:

```
   btn_find.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            // отправляет введенную пользователем ссылку в обработку, показывает гифку ожидания

            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            showGif();
                        }
                    });
                }
            }).start();
```

Метод showGif():

```
private void showGif() {
    System.out.println("запускаю гифку");

    File file = new File("/Users/user/Desktop/cat-preloader.gif");

    String localUrl = null;
    try {
        localUrl = file.toURI().toURL().toString();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Image image = new Image(localUrl, 200,200, false, true);
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(image);

    hb = new HBox();

    hb.setStyle("-fx-background-color: lightgrey");
    hb.setOpacity(0.7);
    hb.getChildren().add(imageView);
    HBox.setMargin(imageView, new Insets(300, 100, 60, 200));
    BorderPane.setMargin(hb, new Insets(0, 0,600, 0));
    MainView.pane.setCenter(hb); // здесь заминка - гиф отображается только после выполнения всей программы

    System.out.println("гифка запущена");

}
```

Comment: А поток с гифкой запускается раньше запуска выполнения основного кода?

Comment: @Z.John нет, после.

Comment: Попробуйте запустить поток с гифкой перед выполнением основного кода. На сколько я понял выполнение основного кода идет в основном потоке.

Comment: @Z.John как, поток с гифкой же привязан к нажатию кнопки? Кнопка создается в основном потоке Application. Если только поставить на кнопку флаг "нажатости" и извне мониторить его бесконечным циклом?

Comment: не совсем понимаю в чем проблема - сейчас у вас в экшене идет основной код и после этого стартует поток с гиф, все что я хотел, чтоб вы поменяли их местами между собой, чтоб сначала стартовал поток с гиф, а после этого вызывался основной метод.

Comment: @anabioze запускайте задачу на фоне в `new Task<>()` и гифку тоже можно запускать этим же способом.

Comment: @anabioze https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/concurrency.htm Смотрите `example 1-1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Запускайте нужный Вам код в бэкграунде что бы не занимать главный поток.

Это можно сделать при помощи `Task`:

```
Task<Void> task = new Task<Void>() {
        @Override protected Integer call() throws Exception {

        System.out.println("запускаю гифку");

        File file = new File("/Users/user/Desktop/cat-preloader.gif");

        String localUrl = null;
        try {
            localUrl = file.toURI().toURL().toString();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Image image = new Image(localUrl, 200,200, false, true);
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(image);

        hb = new HBox();

        hb.setStyle("-fx-background-color: lightgrey");
        hb.setOpacity(0.7);
        hb.getChildren().add(imageView);
        HBox.setMargin(imageView, new Insets(300, 100, 60, 200));
        BorderPane.setMargin(hb, new Insets(0, 0,600, 0));
        MainView.pane.setCenter(hb);

        System.out.println("гифка запущена");

        return null;
    }
};
```

Ну и сам запуск:

`new Thread(task).start()`

так же можно запускать долгие операции в таких же Тасках.

- `Platform.runLater`: Если вам нужно обновить компонент GUI из потока, отличного от GUI, вы можете использовать это, чтобы поместить свое обновление в очередь, и оно будет обрабатываться потоком GUI как можно скорее.
- `Task` реализует интерфейс Worker, который используется, когда вам нужно запустить длинную задачу за пределами потока графического интерфейса (во избежание замораживания вашего приложения), но все же необходимо взаимодействовать с графическим интерфейсом на определенном этапе.

[Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13792889/4444092)